# Back-Button Style jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Problem with the style of my back button.

I include the standard css from jquery mobile and I include the iPhone-style in my side.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />  //from http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/7240874402/ios-inspired-jquery-mobile-theme-jquery-mobile
```

I create a header:

```
 <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Meine Dokumente</h1>
      <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Back
      </a>
 </div>
```

But the style of the back button is the following and not a typically iPhone style.

[image]

Comment: Maybe its missing the background image `images/backButtonSprite.png`